# Does every plane quartic give rise to a cubic surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ be a cubic surface. Let $x\in X$ be a fixed point. Projection from $x$ gives rise to a morphism $\mathrm{Bl}_x(X)\subset \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})\to\mathbb{P}^2$, ramified over a plane quartic curve $C$.

Conversely, given a plane quartic $C$ with equation $s\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(4))$, we can take the ramfied covering $Y\subset\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})$ difined by $y^2=s$. When $C$ is smooth, we know $Y$ is smooth, $K_Y=\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)$, and $|-K_Y|$ gives the double cover.

Can this $Y$ be naturally made into a cubic surface?

(The moduli of cubic surfaces is $4$ dimensional, while the moduli of degree $4$ plane curves is $6$ dimensional, chooice of a point on surface $x\in X$ adds $2$ dimensions, so naive dimension count seems to show that they should match?)

Comment: You have to choose a "line" in $Y$ (a smooth rational curve of square $-1$) and blow it down. It is a standard exercise to show that the resulting surface $Z$ has $K_Z^2=3$ and that $\lvert -K_Z\rvert$ maps $Z$ isomorphically to a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: @abx Thanks! I think the 28 bitangents should provide 56 such curves, as $C^2=-2-CK_Y=-1$ by projection formula, they should be all the $(-1)$ curves on a del pezzo surface of degree $2$

Comment: That's right, each bitangent gives two (-1) curves on the double cover, and conversely.